# javascript comparison of strings

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following script

```
document.write("12" < "2");
```

which returns true. Any reason why? The documentation says that javascript compares strings numerically but, I don't see how "12" is less than "2".

Comment: What documentation did you see that in? It is incorrect. They're compared lexicographically.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FExpressions_and_Operators

Comment: The page you linked to says `"Strings are compared based on standard lexicographical ordering, using Unicode values."` That means that `'12' < '2'` just like `'a2' < 'b'`.

Comment: @Paulpro - Got it (sorry).  Didn't realize that came from the OP.  Deleting my comment....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript compares strings character by character until one of the characters is different.

1 is less than 2 so it stops comparing after the first character.

Comment: ... this is called lexicographical comparison.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it is doing a lexicographic comparison - the first char in string one is '1', which is less than the first char of string two, which is '2'. More about Lexicographic order here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Answer (score 3):

This is because the first character of `"12"` is `1`, which comes before `"2"`; and JavaScript string comparison is lexically/alphabetically, rather than numerically. Though it appears partially numeric, since `1` is sorted ahead of `2`.

You can, however, simply compare the numbers *as numbers*:

```
document.write(parseFloat("12") < parseFloat("2"));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
document.write(parseInt("12") < parseInt("2"));
```

Comment: Presumably because while it solves the 'problem,' it *doesn't* answer the question (not my down-vote, though).

Comment: i guess cuz author asked why it happens. And I propose the solution and not the answer for question)

Comment: @BuDen - If you add one sentence of explanation, this answer would be quite a bit more effective.